# My device is soft-bricked after some system errors

Tags: boot, system-error

Welcome!

Edit: the phone is => Prestigio Multiphone 5451 DUO, android version is 4.2.2

In the past days, I decided to download the larger Messenger app, and removed previously installed "lite" messeger app, and installed facebook lite app, and previously installed the larger FB app. And my phone stuck in a boot-loop. :(

After that, I browsed websites with Google Chrome app, then my phone started freezing with some org.android messages, then accidently the stock launcher is stopped too. I restarted the device, then a message showed up => "encryption unsuccessfull" like in this image

[image: none]

I unfortunately pressed the "reset phone" button, but it don't did anything so I unplugged my battery. Now, when it boot, it stuck in the logo.

Only thing I can do is to boot into stock recovery mode(vol_up, power and Home), and factory mode(vol_down and power)

I can "sideload" with ADB in Recovery Mode, but can't flash due to android signature? .. //edit: but PC sees the device.
I tried by listening adb on boot with both linux/windows, but they can't detect it..

I think someone can help me, I don't want to throw away a whole phone, because others fight with famine and so on. :(

Cheers, LeFizzy.

Comment: What is the phone model, android version? I guess it's a Wiko or Blu phone

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Phone model is Prestigio Multiphone 5451 Duo, and the android version is 4.2.2

Comment: so Android will not boot ?

Comment: Yes, as you said. It just keeps showing the logo. :(

Comment: This happens when the eMMC is corrupted. Flashing ROM should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Flashing the phone should solve the issue but you'll lose all your personal data.

Download the stock firmware [here](http://www.prestigio.com/catalogue/Archive_products/MultiPhones_-_Archive/MultiPhone_5451_DUO#/product-support?article=PAP5451DUOWHITE), Click on Support tab.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Now the problem is that I cannot find the stock firmware by searching "5451", just if I enter "5450" but I cannot apply this update for mine, due to certification. And the second link is filled with surveys only, and I don't trust such a site. :I

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll update with new links when I get home.I didn't test any of them.

Comment: I remember I got only one update in the past 2 years(I bought it in 2014) but I cannot find a firm that could be it. So funny, because they released this OTA somehow. :D

Comment: Updated the link. It's safe now :D

Comment: I have found this article too, but when I try to apply with "apply update from ADB" it's just throw => "assert failed: apply_patch_check("/system/app/ApplicationGuide.apk"). Then I just opened updater_script to see whats inside, then theres bunch of asserts like it. Maybe I deleted this apk file, then it cannot found it? :(

Answer (score 0):

Flashing the stock firmware / ROM to your device would solve the problem, but your device needs to be rooted, in order to install a custom recovery, which would allow you to install custom ROMs (the ROM that you will install is a stock version.)

You should install the ROM that is appropriate for your device.